# javascript multidimensional array acting strangely

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, post, multidimensional-array

I am trying to setup a jquery autocomplete input based on the user's input in a previous field.

I have a php script that returns a json variable to this jquery post function. however I can't seem to set up my array correctly after.

I have tried just setting a variable to the data and processing the array outside of the $.post function, but still no luck.

I am just unsure how and why the sub-value of my array is alerted correctly when the "parent" value as such is shown as null?

```
function populateMetrics(light_id){
    var availableMetrics = [];
    $.post( 
            "getLightMetrics.php",
            { 
              light_id: light_id,
            },
            function(data) {
                $.each(data, function(index, item){
                    alert(index); //correct index
                    availableMetrics[index] = [];
                    availableMetrics[index]['value'] = item.benchmark_id;
                    alert(availableMetrics[index]['value']); //correct value
                    alert(availableMetrics[index]); //null?
                    availableMetrics[index]['label'] = item.benchmark_variant + "-" + item.benchmark_metric;
                    alert(availableMetrics[index]['label']); //correct
                    alert(item.benchmark_id + " = " + item.benchmark_variant + "-" + item.benchmark_metric);
                    alert(availableMetrics[index]); //still null
                });
                alert(availableMetrics); //all null, but correct amount
                $( "#metric" ).autocomplete({
                    source: availableMetrics,
                    focus: function( event, ui ) {
                        $( "#metric" ).val( ui.item.label );
                        return false;
                    },
                    select: function( event, ui ) {
                        $( "#metric" ).val( ui.item.label );
                        $( "#metric_id" ).val( ui.item.value );
                        return false;
                    }
                });
            },
            "json"

    );
}
```

Comment: FYI, don't use alert to debug code, use your console. But do you mean: `alert(availableMetrics[index]);` shows `null`? There is a difference between `null` and empty value, just saying

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multi-dimensional arrays in JavaScript can only have integer-based indexes. They don't work like Associate Arrays do in PHP.

The code you're looking for is probably

```
var availableMetrics = [];

$.each(data, function(index, item) {
    availableMetrics[index] = {
        value: item.benchmark_id,
        label: item.benchmark_variant + "-" + item.benchmark_metric
    };
});
```

This will create an array of objects that have `value` and `label` properties. You would then be able to retrieve the values from your array using either of these notations:

```
availableMetrics[index]['value'];
availableMetrics[index].value;
```

Comment: worked perfectly, however i used the same technique i showed above on another part of the page. and it worked, however it wasn't in a $.post function